# overriding module caption names in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, customization

By default, the admin models are grouped by the app, and the app name is in the caption (accounts, auth, etc.). How to override the name in the caption without writing the admin templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, django doesn't provide any easy way to do this. See [this ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3591).

Answer (score 6):

You can easily doing it through the metadata options app_label and db_table

```
class model_module1(models.model):
    [...]

    class Meta:
        app_label = "Cool module name"
        db_table = "module1_model"


class model_module2(models.model):
    [...]

    class Meta:
        app_label = "Cool module name"
        db_table = "module2_model"
```

If you configure tables names correctly you will see how your modules get grouped under the new label in the admin.

Ref: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label

Comment: I just get an error: "Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'My App'}' not found."

Comment: **This is an incorrect answer!** This only works for a model defined outside of an installed app.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for Django 2:

In *apps.py* file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
    verbose_name = 'My App Name'
```

In *settings.py* file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp.apps.Config',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help somewhat. You can change how the apps are grouped, although I don't think you can change the app name:

django-grappelli

http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/