# Django Admin Interface - Custom App Name

Tags: django, admin

Using the 'app_label' in the 'Class Meta' will solve this problem. But it won't create tables while issuing 'syncdb' command.  Because the app name won't match with INSTALLED_APPS entry. Is there any way to achieve both (custom app name and creating tables with syncdb)

Comment: Are you trying to have custom table names? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dominic I think he wants to change the application names(labels) which appear in the admin interface to some custom names.

Comment: @Dominic @anand is correct. I would like to have custom application names in the admin interface.

Comment: The problem here is that, if we use app_label in models, it won't create the database tables while doing 'syncdb'.

Comment: Not an elegant solution but you can follow the second answer in the stackoverflow.com/questions/612372/ . Copy admin template and define app name there.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453112/overriding-module-caption-names-in-django-admin/3629378#3629378) there is a solution that should allow changing the app label while working with `syncdb`.

```js
class model_module1(models.model):
    [...]

    class Meta:
        app_label = "Cool module name"
        db_table = "module1_model"

class model_module2(models.model):
    [...]

    class Meta:
        app_label = "Cool module name"
        db_table = "module2_model"
```

This makes sense, since the name of the table is made explicit, so there is no `guessing` when running `syncdb`. The downside is that this two `Meta` options must be specified in every model of the app.