# UnicodeEncodeError when changing the app_label in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057575/django-admin-interface-custom-app-name), I have changed my model like this:

```
class MyModel(User):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name=u"my app verbose name"
        app_label = u"My Members"
        db_table = "members_mymodel"
```

Now I have an error when going to app in django admin:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):



File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 146, in get_response
    response = debug.technical_404_response(request, e)

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 294, in technical_404_response
    'reason': smart_str(exception, errors='replace'),

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 123, in smart_str
    errors) for arg in s])

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 124, in smart_str
    return unicode(s).encode(encoding, errors)

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 191, in __repr__
    return '<%s %s (%s:%s) %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.urlconf_name, self.app_name, self.namespace, self.regex.pattern)

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 191, in __repr__
    return '<%s %s (%s:%s) %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.urlconf_name, self.app_name, self.namespace, self.regex.pattern)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0130' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

admin link :

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/My%20Members/
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide us the whole stacktrace please

Comment: I dont think you're allowed to place "space" character in your ``app_label``. Also it should be lowercase only.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an odd character (`\u0130`) somewhere in your codebase. That character is a "latin capital letter i with a dot above": İ. Try searching for that and removing it.

If you're using UTF-8 characters in your `.py` files, declare them as being UTF-8 by adding this as the first line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I have to use charactres that using in foreign languages. But now in my model, without any special character, I have the same error. Thanks

Comment: Where are you using these characters then? Do you have them in a `.py` file somewhere within your project? They could still cause issues when they get imported.

Comment: I am using them in models.py in app_label

Comment: I've updated my answer, you should declare that your file contains UTF-8 characters.

Comment: I have '#encoding: utf-8' line in my all .py files. # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- also not sense :( I think that I use different way to change my app names in django admin

Comment: Or use HTML entities instead - such as `&#304;`.